# How can I give admin permissions to my account?

Tags: login, users, administrator

11.10 has allowed me to (stupidly) remove my admin level login leaving me with only my standard log in. I am no longer able to modify any software, update etc.

How can I 'uprate' my user login back up to admin level?

Answer (score 3):

Follow [any of the procedures for resetting a forgotten password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) (or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121698/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-password-using-recovery-mode-requires-me-to-type-the-pass/147023#147023), or [this](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)), but ***do not*** run:

`passwd username`

Instead, run:

`usermod -a -G sudo username`

Of course, **`username`** should be replaced with your actual username.

**Note:** if you are on Ubuntu 11.10 or an older release, the command to run is:

`usermod -a -G admin username`

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 10.10 `admin` group was not enough after creating the new user with `adduser username`. I also had to make the user memeber of the `sudo` group:

```
usermod -a -G admin,sudo username
```