# How can I give my account admin powers again?

Tags: password-recovery, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i give Admin permissions to my account?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84474/how-can-i-give-admin-permissions-to-my-account)

When I installed Ubuntu I used a password and "admin" type account. But accidentally I changed it's type to "standard". So I can't use any privileges right now.

At least I can't access any of my partitions. When I try to access them the system asks for a password and says my old password is wrong.